# What's a good workflow for keeping track of which TODO items I've worked on in the last week in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Right now I'm just using inactive timestamps for some TODO items and updating them when I'm working on that item. I figured out how to get them to show up in the Timeline view.

Is there a better workflow to achieve this? Especially e.g. having a quicker way to update the timestamp on an item.

Comment: @OwenBeresford: I'm using org.mode and I'd like to continue using it. I added org.mode to the title since it was maybe unclear before from just using the tags.

Comment: Have you used the clocking settings in Org at all?

Comment: `C-c .` to change a timestamp underneath the cursor; or, place the cursor on a digit in the timestamp and use `shift-arrow-up` or `shift-arrow-down`.  I have a function that carries forward all overdue tasks and sets the timestamp to today, and also changes the status from Next Action to Active.  There is also a function in these threads (about a month ago) that changes the timestamps of all tasks within a selected region:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493745/org-deadline-change-all-in-selected-block-in-one-fell-swoop

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the function to carry forward all uncompleted todo is in this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642937/how-to-exclude-or-marker-p-when-using-deadline-today

Answer (score 0):

As already mentionned, you definitely have to use clocking commands for this (C-c C-x C-i/j/o). See the manual.

Then, when jumping on whichever day or week (or ...) of the agenda view, you can ask for seeing those "hidden" past entries by pressing 'v l' (view > log). Press 'v' in the agenda, and have a look at all possible commands ('v [' as well for viewing the inactive timestamps).